# Google Apps Script performing Index & Match function between two separate Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Apps Script to perform a Index and Match function between two separate Google Sheets and retrieve the matching records and populate the designated sheet and column. Although it works fairly well, I would like to get the script to run more efficiently and as such use less time. Could Someone please look at the code example below and provide me with advice/pointers to do so

```
function SiteIDLookup() {
var search_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("GoogleSheetId");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(search_spreadsheet);
var find_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("GoogleSheetId");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(find_spreadsheet);
var ssheet = search_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("schoolSiteID_Lookup");
var fsheet = find_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Info_Formatted");
var FMaxR = fsheet.getMaxRows();
fsheet.getRange(2, 16, FMaxR, 1).clear({contentsOnly: true});
var findData = fsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var searchData = ssheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for(var i=0; i < findData.length; i++) {
 for(var j=0; j < searchData.length; j++) {
  var find = findData[i][14];
  var searchref = searchData[j][0];

  if(find == searchref && find != "" ) {
   var found = ssheet.getRange(j+1,2,1,1).getDisplayValue();
   fsheet.getRange(i+1,16,1,1).setValue(found);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: How about editing data in array? At "for" loops, there is a setValue. It retrieves data of "fsheet" using getValues, edits the data array at "for" loops. After it exits from "for" loop, it overwrites the edited data array to "fsheet" using "setValues". I think that it leads to reduction of usage count of API and speed up. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 2):

The comment on your question is pretty much correct. You are doing unnecessary actions like

```
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(search_spreadsheet);
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(find_spreadsheet);
```

which serve no purpose. Then inside of the loops you perform an unnecessary action

```
var found = ssheet.getRange(j+1,2,1,1).getDisplayValue();
```

considering you already did `var searchData = ssheet.getDataRange().getValues();` that command line is redundant and is performed at each iteration to boot. You have 2 data sets in arrays, you need to work with arrays and use `.setValues(array)` to output the data. Something along the lines of this (you would have to check the indexing etc, since I don't have the actual sheets to test this on)

```
function SiteIDLookup() {
//  --------------------------------------------------------------------
//  This bit is purely cosmetic, I personaly hate declaring variables
//  inside of loops or middle of the code
  var i, j
  var find
  var searchref
  var found = []
//  --------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  var search_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("GoogleSheetId");  
  var find_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("GoogleSheetId");
  
  var ssheet = search_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("schoolSiteID_Lookup");
  var fsheet = find_spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Info_Formatted");
  var FMaxR = fsheet.getMaxRows();
  
  fsheet.getRange(2, 16, FMaxR, 1).clear({contentsOnly: true});
  
  var findData = fsheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var searchData = ssheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  for (i = 0; i < findData.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < searchData.length; j++) {
      
      find = findData[i][14];
      searchref = searchData[j][0];
      
      if (find == searchref && find != "" ) {
        found[i] = searchData[j][1]
      }
      else {
        found[i] = ['']
      }
      //        found = ssheet.getRange(j+1,2,1,1).getDisplayValue();
      //        fsheet.getRange(i+1,16,1,1).setValue(found);
    }
  }
  
  fsheet.getRange(2, 16, found.length, 1).setValues(found)
}
```