# Google Apps Script: how to copy paste ranges based on formulas?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a model in Google Sheets that is set up with one column per day. It contains both actuals and forecasts, and every day I need to roll forward formulas to replace forecasts with actuals. I can't roll forward the whole column, only a segment of it (there are reference numbers above and below that shouldn't be changed).

I have tried to write a script to do this for me every day, but I don't know how to make `getRange` reference a dynamic range. This is my attempt:

```
function rollColumn() {
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<ID redacted>');
  ss2.getRange("=index(Model!$7:$7,,match(today()-2,Model!$4:$4,0)):index(Model!$168:$168,,match(today()-2,Model!$4:$4,0))").copyTo(ss2.getRange("=index(Model!$7:$7,,match(today()-1,Model!$4:$4,0)):index(Model!$168:$168,,match(today()-1,Model!$4:$4,0))"))
};
```

The `INDEX` formulas work insofar as they reference the relevant ranges (I have tested them in the spreadsheet). But clearly `getRange` doesn't accept formulas as an input. It also seems that Google Sheets doesn't allow for a named range to be created with formulas (which is how I would solve this in Excel).

Can someone help me recreate this functionality with GAS?

This is the closest existing question I've found on Stack Overflow, but I haven't been able to make it work:
[Google Apps Script performing Index & Match function between two separate Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968207/google-apps-script-performing-index-match-function-between-two-separate-google)

Thank you!

Comment: It is unclear whether you have tried using logs or just if you know JavaScript. Right now, the main problem with your code is that you are trying to get a Google Sheets formula to work in a script. However, Google Sheets formulas only work when written in Google Sheets. Please send a link to a sample Google Sheet with Index-match in it. Then I will help and provide code that replicates its behaviour.

Comment: Thank you Antoine for your quick reply. Here is a simplified sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BU2rhAZGOLYgzgSAdEz4fJkxEcPRpwl_TZ1SR5F0y08/edit?usp=sharing

The point is that once the previous day's data comes in, in this case I would need to copy `M4:M6` into `N4:N6`

I have included a formula in yellow that shows how I would get to that range based on today's date, but I'm sure the script solution could end up quite different.. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the link but I cannot see the formula. Could you change the sharing settings to [public on the web](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)? So that everyone who sees your question can see it?

Comment: Thank you Antoine, I have given you edit access and can respond to any further requests. Sheet should be viewable by anyone through the link.

Answer (score 1):

You should add {contentsOnly:false} parameter to your code. something like this:

```
TemplateSheet.getRange("S2:T2").copyTo(DestSheet.getRange("S2:T"+LRow2+""), {contentsOnly:false});
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a date from column's title, then pasting formulas to the row to the right:

```
// note: we assume that sheet is disposed as in the following document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BU2rhAZGOLYgzgSAdEz4fJkxEcPRpwl_TZ1SR5F0y08/edit?ts=5a32fcc5#gid=0
function find_3formulas() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      leftTitle, // this variable will stay unused because we do not need a vertical index
      topTitle = todayMinus_xDays(2),
      topTitlesRange = sheet.getRange("G3:T3"),
      leftTitlesRange = sheet.getRange("A4:A8"); // this range will stay unused.

  var coor = findCoordinates(leftTitlesRange, leftTitle, topTitlesRange, topTitle);

  if (coor.row == null || coor.column == null) {
    sheet.getRange("M12:M14").setFormula('="NULL: please check logs"'); 
    return;
  }

  var rowAxis = 4 + coor.row;
  var colAxis = 8 + coor.column;
  var fromRange = sheet.getRange(rowAxis, colAxis, 3, 1);
  var toRange = sheet.getRange(rowAxis, colAxis + 1, 3, 1);

  Logger.log(fromRange.getA1Notation())
  Logger.log(toRange.getA1Notation());

  var threeFormulas = fromRange.getFormulas();

  toRange.setFormulas(threeFormulas)
}

// unused in current script!
function findCoordinates(leftTitlesRange, leftTitle, topTitlesRange, topTitle) {

  var formattedDate, 
      row = 0, 
      column = 0;

  if (leftTitle) {
    row = findRow(leftTitlesRange, leftTitle);
  }

  if (topTitle) {
    column = findColumn(topTitlesRange, topTitle);
  }

  var array = {row:row, column:column}

  return array;
}

// unused in current script!
function findRow(range, valueToSearch) {

  var colRows = range.getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < colRows.length; i++) {
    if (valueToSearch == colRows[i][0]) {return i;}
  } 
  // however, if found nothing: 
  Logger.log("the value " + valueToSearch + " could not be found in row titles");
  return null;
}

// assumes that column titles are dates, therefore of type object.
function findColumn(range, valueToSearch) {

  var colTitles = range.getValues();
  for (i = 0; i < colTitles[0].length; i++) { 
    if (typeof colTitles[0][i] == "object") {
      formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(colTitles[0][i], "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd")
    };
    if (valueToSearch === formattedDate) {return i;}
  }
  // however, if found nothing:
  Logger.log("today's date, " + valueToSearch + ", could not be found in column titles");
  return null;
}

// substracts 2 days from today, then returns the result in string format.
function todayMinus_xDays(x) {
  var d = new Date();
  d = new Date(d - x * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  d = Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
  return d;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Unfortunately, I don't think this script does quite what I had in mind as I need to paste the formulas rather than the values, and I'm not 100% sure how to rework it. In natural language terms, what I need a script to do is:
a) Within area $4:$8, find column matched on today's date minus 2 days (using $3:$3).
b) Copy this range (currently N4:N8) to one column along (O4:O8), preserving formulas and formatting.
Is that an easy fix?

Comment: Ok now the code does all that. Let me know if it works for you