# Google Apps Script doing Index Match function gives array[0].length = undefined despite being in form [[value], [value]...]

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, match

I'm using Google Apps Script to perform an Index-Match function on 2 sheets in the same Spreadsheet, and I've adapted the code in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968207/google-apps-script-performing-index-match-function-between-two-separate-google).

However, when I try to setValues() using the array found, I get this error:
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 1.

I've looked at the array that I created using the function (found) and it matches the right dimensions of [[value], null, [value], ..., [value]].  Can anyone explain why this is so, and any ideas on how to fix it?  Is it because there are null values in the array?

Note that the sourcedata table has more rows than the find table and there are some rows that do not have a lookup value, for which I would like a null value.  I can do this function using the createTextfinder function but it's not as efficient as using the 2 for-loops to create the arrays.  Or perhaps there are better alternatives that I should explore?

```
function indexMatch() {
  var basesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("source");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("findtable");
  var found = [];
  var searchData = basesheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var findData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 
  for (i = 0; i < findData.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < searchData.length; j++) {
      var find = findData[i][5];
      var searchref = searchData[j][19];
      if (find == searchref && find != "") {
        found[[i]] = [searchData[j][8]];
      }
    } 
  }
  Logger.log(found);
  sheet.getRange(1, 7, found.length, 1).setValues(found)
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem lies in found[[i]].   I don't think you can access an array element using [[]].  Also, in the script you are referencing, there is an else that puts an empty array in the found array.  I am not sure how app script handles setting null values.

Comment: You need to explain more what you are trying to do. You code is not something people normally do with loops.

Comment: @KrispinMiller if I specify the else to return found[i] = null, it returns everything as null in the array.

Comment: @idfurw I'm trying to lookup a value in another table in google sheets, and some of them do not exist, which I want to return a null value.  I have managed to do it with another code using createtextfinder() but I'm trying to understand what I did wrong here.

Comment: `found.push([searchData[j][8]])` as provided by Cooper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you're array looks like this: `[[value], null, [value], ..., [value]]`

I believe it should look like this: `[[value], [null], [value], ..., [value]]`

Try this:

```
function indexMatch() {
  var basesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("source");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("findtable");
  var found = [];
  var searchData = basesheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var findData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 
  for (i = 0; i < findData.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < searchData.length; j++) {
      var find = findData[i][5];
      var searchref = searchData[j][19];
      if (find == searchref && find != "") {
        found.push([searchData[j][8]]);
      }
    } 
  }
  Logger.log(found);
  sheet.getRange(1, 7, found.length, 1).setValues(found)
}
```

I'm not absolutedly sure but I think the below code will works as well:

```
function indexMatch() {
  var basesheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("source");
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("findtable");
  var found = [];
  var search = basesheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var find = sh.getRange(1, 6, sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
  for (j = 0; j < search.length; j++) {
    if(~find.indexOf(search[j][18]))found.push([search[j][8]]);
  }
  sh.getRange(1, 7, found.length, 1).setValues(found)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Cooper, thanks for that.  The first code posted doesn't push a null at all, so instead of 351 rows (or found.length = 351), I get 301 rows instead.  The second code snippet doesn't work and throws the following exception: "The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.".  I looked at the log and it returned an empty array.